# Windows 10 Application - iot systemManagement capability

Tags: c#, windows, timezone, uwp, iot

We have Windows 10 application and we are trying to change time zone on the system.

I have found documentation about having IOT extensions included into the project, what would give basic system administration capabilities.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.timezonesettings.changetimezonebydisplayname

So far, I failed to get permission to do anything (reboot system, change time zone etc), always get auth exception.

This is what I have tried:

manifest (important parts):

```
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp iot">

<Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.10586.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.10586.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.IoT" MinVersion="10.0.10586.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.10586.0" />
  </Dependencies>

 <Capabilities>
    <iot:Capability Name="systemManagement" />  
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

code:

```
 Boolean canChange = Windows.System.TimeZoneSettings.CanChangeTimeZone;
 Windows.System.TimeZoneSettings.ChangeTimeZoneByDisplayName("(UTC+13:00) Samoa");
```

reference to IOT added to project

Comment: Is this actually running on a Windows IOT device?

Comment: It is running on Windows 10 tablet. Some of the methods are available, such as: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.timezonesettings.supportedtimezonedisplaynames.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1 , var supportedTimeZoneDisplayNames = Windows.System.TimeZoneSettings.supportedTimeZoneDisplayNames;   This works and lists all time zones. If I call method to change time zone, I get unauthorized exception. This makes me believe that these methods exist in regular Windows 10 and I just need to obtain permissions.

Comment: Seems there is no way to make this work in regular windows 10.

Comment: Any Idea how would one change system time or time zone programmatically in Windows 10?

Comment: Interesting that Shutdown, change TimeZone are all working on my Raspberry Pi 2.

Comment: No, same exception, not authorized.

Comment: Difference is, I need this on Windows 10 tablet/desktop machine. From MSDN documentation, it says IoT extension available from Win build version 10240 +, and I have newer. So, It seems like the api is there, but Windows does not give permission to use it. I will have to see if there is a way to run external process to run tzutil or something like that.

Comment: I see. Looks like IoT extension are only for IoT devices, you cannot just reference the IoT extension in your regular UWP project and expect the IoT APIs to work on your Desktop/tablet, can you?

Comment: By the way, if you want to do the system level operations like shutdown/change timezone, you may reference this tutorial https://xamltips.wordpress.com/2015/11/13/brokered-component-for-uwp-on-windows-10/ to create an brokered component.

Comment: Thanks Jackie, I will check out the tutorial.

Comment: Not sure it'll work out. But the point is IoT extension are only meant for windows IoT devices. I'm suggesting we put that as an answer so that others an have reference.

Comment: In case someone might need this. Workaround can be to launch Windows settings screen: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOT: as Jackie said: 
"Not sure it'll work out. But the point is IoT extension are only meant for windows IoT devices"

However, I did find a workaround...

If anyone else encounters this problem.

I have run a local lightweight NancyFX web service that has an access to system settings. From an UWP application, I will make api calls and change system settings this way.

see http://nancyfx.org/ and self hosting example

Also, if calling localhost from edge, you will need to setup a loopback app exception, see https://loopback.codeplex.com/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780593.aspx

Pretty much everything works after that.

Comment: that sounds awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Old threat but when i search for my solution to this IoT systemManagement manifest i stumble into this. I using VS2017. My fix is 
View code package manifest manually. Then add this line

```
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" 
xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" 
xmlns:uap4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/4" 
xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap4 iot">

<Capabilities>
    <iot:Capability Name="systemManagement"/> 
<Capabilities>
```

*Remember you can only declare 1 Capabilites so if you had declare just add new.

Then add capability in manifest with this code

And plus go to add reference->Extension select
Windows IoT Extensions for the UWP version 10.0.10586.0
*even you have newer version must select this to work.